# MySQL: How to select all register on table A that does not appears on table B?

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I need to discover which registers are on table A and doesn't appears on table B.

But - not only - I need only QUESTIONS with TYPE 2 - and ANSWERS from USERID 1

```
Table A: QUESTIONS
QUESTIONID QUESTION  TYPE
1           ABC       1
2           DEF       2
3           GHI       2
4           JKL       2

Table B: ANSWERS
ANSWERID QUESTIONID USERID  
1            1        1
2            1        2
3            2        1
4            4        1


RESULT:
QUESTIONID 
3
```

I try a lot of "Joins" but no one returns the corret result.

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS 
LEFT JOIN ANSWERS ON QUESTIONS.QUESTIONID = ANSWERS.QUESTIONID
WHERE TYPE = 2 AND USERID = 1
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A an exists query should work here:

```
SELECT a.QUESTIONID
FROM TableA a
WHERE
    a.TYPE = 2 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b
                WHERE a.QUESTIONID = b.QUESTIONID AND b.USERID = 1);
```

Comment: hi @Tim-Biegeleisen - first of all tks for your precious time to help me! yes.. works, but not solve the problem with only type 2 questions answered by user 1. Maybe I need to complete the where clause right?

Comment: @DANIEL Sorry, I either did not read the entire question or missed that requirement.  Check the updated answer.

Comment: hi @Tim-bielgeleisen - great! works fine now!! tks a lot!! :D